# via in pad, thermal via, or something else?

Tags: pcb-design, repair, via

So recently while watching a video I came across this:

[image: bottom side]

to me this looks like a pad with a bunch of vias in it. I haven't encountered multiple vias in the same pad before. I tried to search images of one, but couldn't find any. So is this something else? It seems a strange design choice to me because:

1. wouldn't all the vias be bridged together? if so, why expose the interconnection, here, in this way?
2. How did the manufacturer manage to cap all of these without solder flowing all over the over pad. I don't see evidence of any masks.

*(for context: the first images is a bottom side of a micro usb connector on an Asus Transformer T102HA, this is the top side)*

[image: topside]

I thought these might be thermal vias (which would make sense considering the charging port will heat up during use)

[image: thermal vias]

Thanks for taking the time to read this. If you're familiar with this design pattern and could alleviate my curiosity, it would be greatly appreciated.

[*The video the first two images came from can be found here.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvqcAuZXdi4)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a small BGA chip? I don't see any other lands for the chip in that first image.

Comment: @RonBeyer That's bare copper, the entire thing is a land. Hence, it is not BGA footprint.

Comment: they're heatsink vias to carry heat to the back of the board I don't know how they got the right amount of solder

Comment: The fact the region surrounding these spots on the bottom side is exposed copper suggests they are thermal vias. The fact there are no such vias visible in the top side view, particularly in the region where the top copper layer has been damaged, makes the question more mysterious.